# Custom fonts won't work in runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

I wrote a program which uses a custom (.ttf) font. I want to be able to export it to a runnable JAR file, but I'm finding that when I create the JAR file, the font doesn't take. It does work fine however if I launch it from Eclipse. The code I used to add the font is:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    try {
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("neuropol x rg.ttf")));
    } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've looked at a bunch of other posts on this subject, and they all seem to indicate that you need to access the font as a resource and not a file, but I'm not 100% sure what the difference between the two is. Every example I looked at also created an instance of a new font, but when I tried some of the code snippets inside my program, using the new font also wouldn't work. Can anybody help to explain this a little for me? Thanks.

Comment: are the fonts in the same path i guess?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that. `neuropol x rg.ttf` is in the project folder (along with `src`, `.settings`, and `bin`).

Comment: If the fonts are included in the Jar, you'll need to use something more like `ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("neuropol x rg.ttf")));`. If not, remember, the path to the fonts is relative to the location the jar was executed from, which isn't always the location the jar is located. It might also be helpful if you included the stack trace, you'll need to run the jar from the command line to get it

Comment: Yeah that definitely a good point about the file location. Using the above code throws the error `Problem reading font data` though.

Comment: In doing a little more research, I read that this error could be due to the fact that Java cannot find the file specified (incorrect path). iIf the file is within the Project folder, should ("neuropol x rg.ttf") be alright for the path? Or should I not be using a relative path?